# returning a new instance of an object

Tags: java, object

I am writing a program to simulate a parking ticket system. In total I 4 distinct classes, these being ParkedCar, ParkingMeter, ParkingTicket and PoliceOfficer. In my PoliceOfficer class I have an if statement to determine if the police officer should issue a ticket for the parked car.

I have the following statement to do such: return new ParkingTicket(this,car,meter). I get an incompatible type error. If I need to post my code for my other classes, let me know.

Parking Ticket Class:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class ParkingTicket {
private static int ticketCount;
private ParkedCar car;
private PoliceOfficer officer;
private ParkingMeter meter;
private double fine;

public final double BASE_FINE = 25.0;
public final double HOURLY_FINE = 10.0;

public ParkingTicket (ParkedCar aCar, PoliceOfficer anOfficer, ParkingMeter aMeter) {
    this.car = aCar;
    this.officer = anOfficer;
    this.meter = aMeter;

    calculateFine();
}


public void calculateFine() {
   // Calculate fine & increment ticket count
   ++ticketCount;

   int timeOver = (int)Math.ceil((car.getMinutesParked() - meter.getMinutesPurchased() / 60.0));
   fine = BASE_FINE * HOURLY_FINE * (timeOver - 1);
}

public String toString() {
    DecimalFormat newDecimal = new DecimalFormat("$###.00");
    return "Ticket Number: " + ticketCount + "\n" +
            car + "\n" + meter + "\n" + "Fine: " + newDecimal.format(fine) + "\n" 
            + officer;
}
}
```

Police Officer Class:

```
public class PoliceOfficer {
// Declare data fields
private String name;
private String badgeNumber;

// Default constructor 
public PoliceOfficer (String name, String badgeNumber) {
    this.name = name;
    this.badgeNumber = badgeNumber;
}

// Copy of PoliceOfficer
public PoliceOfficer (PoliceOfficer OfficerCopy) {
    this.name = OfficerCopy.name;
    this.badgeNumber = OfficerCopy.badgeNumber;
}

// Class to check a parked car and determine if the 
// cars time has expired
public ParkingTicket check(ParkedCar car, ParkingMeter meter) {

if (car.getMinutesParked() > meter.getMinutesPurchased()) {
    // Creating a new object of ParkingTicket object
    return new ParkingTicket(this,car,meter);
 } else {
    return null;
 }
}

// toString class
public String toString() {
  return "Officer Name: " + name + "/n" + "Badge ID: " + badgeNumber;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just got your arguments reversed. The `ParkingTicket` constructor requires its arguments to be:

```
(ParkedCar, PoliceOfficer, ParkingMeter)
```

But you're passing

```
(PoliceOfficer, ParkedCar, ParkingMeter)
```

All you need to do is change the call to `new ParkingTicket(car, this, meter)`.

Comment: Forgot that my ParkingTicket signature needs to match when I make the call to create a new ParkingTicket object. Thanks for the quick help :)

Answer (score 1):

You mention instantiating `ParkingTicket` in `PoliceOfficer` (so `this` is `PoliceOfficer`)

```
new ParkingTicket(this,car,meter)
```

I believe it should be

```
new ParkingTicket(car,this,meter)
```

Because the constructor signature is `ParkingTicket(ParkedCar, PoliceOfficer, ParkingMeter)`